# Edges only graph/hyper-graph like object?

Tags: graph-theory, hypergraphs

I've been exploring a possibly novel graph/hyper-graph like structure where edges can connect other edges together and nodes are not needed. For the purposes of this question I'll refer to this sort of graph as "edge-connecting".

For example the following describes a labelled, "vertexless", "edge-connecting" graph.

```
{1, 2}
{1, 3}
{2, 3}
```

Each row of this table is a set and represents an edge. The first row states that "edge 1" connects edges 1 and 2. In the 2nd row "edge 2" connects edges 1 and 3, and so on.

I found a way to visually draw this graph (embedding in R^2), draw a curved or straight line segment for each edge and label it. Each segment terminates at the two edges it connects. I found it visually clear to have segments end against others at 90 degrees. As with non "edge-connecting" graphs some redrawing may be required for a satisfactory embedding.

To get all 6 such graphs with 3 edges, permute the rows in the table above. There are fewer than 6 if unlabelled rather than labelled. Being that the graph is not a multi-graph the following situations cannot arise:

```
1 1
This edges "ends" are the same,
connecting "edge 1" to itself.
```

.

```
2 2
1 2
"Edge 1" has a similar problem.
```

.

```
1 2
1 2
The edges are identical.
The set {1, 2} = {1, 2}.
```

---

Multiple separate empty edges seem to behave like nodes:

```
{}
{}
{1 2}
{2 4}
```

Four edges, two of them node like and connected by "edge 3".

---

Allowing edges that individually connect more than 2 edges makes the construction more like a hyper-graph. In this case a "simple vertexless edge-connecting hyper-graph".

```
1, 2, 3
1, 3, 4, 5
1, 2
2, 3
3, 4
```

---

**Properties**

It's simpler to just have edges and not nodes.

At least when labelled, there are enormously more of these constructions than ordinary graphs.

cite: [Wolfram Alpha](https://wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28%28%28n+-+1%29+*+n+%2F+2%29+choose+n%29+*+%28n%21%29%29%2C+%282%5E%28%28n+*+%28n+-+1%29%29+%2F+2%29%29)

Adding edges expands and changes the structure of the graph more than in a conventional graph.

Instead of separate Vertex and Edge transitivity, such graphs may simply have "transitivity".

There are no vertexless edge-connecting graphs with 1 or 2 edges.

Even more so there are no vertexless edge-connecting hypergraphs with 1 or 2 edges, as long as each edge connects the same number of edges.

They should work with existing concepts such as "simple", "multi", "fully connected", labelled/unlabelled, finite/infinite, addition, types of multiplication, transitivity, and graph colouring.

---

**Question**

Are these already named? Are there contradictions or other problems with the construction that I've missed?

---

**Combinatorics**

Counting labelled graphs:

2 ^ ((N * (N - 1)) / 2)

.

Counting labelled edge-connecting graphs with V vertex like edges + N larger edges.

((Triangle(N - 1) + V) choose N) * (N!)

hyper:

((Subsets(N) + V - 1) choose N) * (N!)

Comment: What sort of objects can be usefully modeled by "edge-connecting graphs"? Ordinary graphs appear whenever you have a set of objects and a relation between them.

Comment: Whenever you have relations between relations? When relations are value like but also connect things. When things are getting very meta and you just need to look at it and analyse for structure/symmetry etc… When nothing is entirely like an object and everything is like a relation. Where specific instances of various binary operations relate. Perumations, Group_Theory, Tensors, Lambda Calculus, Axioms, Representation_Theory

Comment: It sounds like you don't have any concrete examples. Abstractions are valuable, but each abstraction should have at least two instances where it's useful.

Answer (score 1):

May I note that relations between edges is not a new concept. This is called a line graph in the literature. you may look at the definition at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph

In addition, I noticed you posted this also in community.wolfram.com
Mathematica has a function LineGraph that generates the corresponding line graph from a given graph

Saying "Edges only" is ignoring the fact that in the first place, an edge is define by its end points (nodes), and two edges are adjacent if they have an end point (node) in common. So, you cannot run away from that...

There are graph that have nodes and no edges. The opposite is not possible...

Comment: An (interesting) operation similar to a duel except about edges and not faces. You end up with another normal graph afterwards though. Edge-connecting graphs are not a subset of graphs but an extension like "directed" is. It allows edges to be defined by having end edges or nodes, not just nodes. Edges can then connect any node to any edge, or any edge to any other edge, not just adjacent ones, and then you can have arbitrarily many edges on the same graph without using the same edge twice (not multi), even when there are no nodes at all. The smallest without nodes ends up having 3 edges.